# How to avoid "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" or "Cannot Read Property of Undefined" when you're using info from "@ViewChild"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to understand some questions about @ViewChild and how it works.
I'm using angular 8, and for some reason I got some errors, such as "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" or "Cannot Read Property ... of Undefined"

I'm tried to use `{static: false}` on my @ViewChild, but I got the same error. So, how could solve this problem and how it works?

I understand, that children components runs after parent being displayed. I used some methods, such as ngAfterViewInit and AfterViewChecked, to wait for the child information, but I got the same error. Am I missing something?

Here is my code below:

**app-parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({ selector: 'app-parent', templateUrl: './app-parent.component.html' })
export class AppParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

  @ViewChild('backbtn', {static: false}) backReference : ChildBackComponent;
  previousurl : string = null;

  /*...codes...*/
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.previousurl = this.backReference.previousUrl;
  }
  /*...codes...*/
```

**app-parent.component.html**

```
<!-- HTML codes -->
<app-child-back-button #backbtn >Button</app-child-back-button>
<app-another-child-element *ngIf="currentUrl" [url]="previousurl" ></app-another-child-element>
```

and

**child-back-button.component.ts**

```
@Component({ selector: "app-child-back-button", templateUrl: "./child-back-button.component.html" })
export class ChildBackComponent implements OnInit {
  public previousUrl: string = "/";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.previousUrl = "/previousurl";
  }
```

**child-back-button.component.html**

```
<a routerLink="{{ previousUrl }}"><ng-content></ng-content></a>
```

---

**Edit**

Thanks to @tony-ngo, I solve this issue.

Just change my code to

**app-parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({ selector: 'app-parent', templateUrl: './app-parent.component.html' })
export class AppParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('backbtn', {static: false}) backReference : ChildBackComponent;
  previousurl : string = null;

  /*...codes...*/
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.previousurl = this.backReference.previousUrl;
    }, 1000);
  }

  /*...codes...*/
```

IMHO, it seems that is not an elegant thing to do, but it solve my issue, and works fine. Maybe you need to wait for all components to become available, before get some info from viewchild.

The other solution seems to be more complex, I have to manage and detect changes, just to solve an issue that only occurs on development mode. So, the first solution is fine to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on this [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-in-angular-what-why-and-how-to-fix-it-c6bdc0b22787) here is couple of way you can fix it

Side note since you are trying to get lastest updated value from your view child you need to update your code

```
@ViewChild('backbtn', {static: true}) backReference : ChildBackComponent;
```

Use setTimeout something like this

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.previousurl = this.backReference.previousUrl;
    }, 1000); // set timeout for 1 second you can change 2000 or 3000
  }
```

Move your logic to ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.previousurl = this.backReference.previousUrl;
  }
```

Use ChangeDection like this

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Or on the other hand, you need to make sure you let Angular pick up changes. The prefered way to do that is using markForCheck.

Comment: Thanks @tony-ngo! I just change some of my code to use `ngAfterViewInit`, and use `setTimeout` inside that.

I'll edit my question.